# Local rules management of outlook

Tags: outlook-redemption

How to manipulate local rules such as those used by a PST store?
I want to copy rules of existing profile of 2013 exchange and add into new profile of 2016 exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Local rules are stored as RWZ files. Redemption does not support RWZ files.

**EDIT**: as of version 6.0, local rule support (along with RWZ files) had been added to Redemption.